# drag and drop sets the source to a transparent image

Tags: jquery, image, drag-and-drop, background, transparent

I have an image bank from which i drag and drop photos onto a container.
i then use a crop plugin on those images to allow the user crop and adjust the image. the crop is done in a crop div while the images in the container display the preview of the crop.

i'm using jQuery UI Draggable and droppable plugins and the wonderful [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) for the cropping and preview.

my problem is this: when dropping the image in the container the plugin sets the background attribute as the source, and the source attribute is set to be a transparent inline encoded image (would love if someone would explain to me the logic behind it).
now to the preview logic of the imgAreaSelect plugin requires that the image will be the source attribute. while i can temporarily replace the attribute of the source and background, this is not an ideal solution.

ideas anyone?

**update**:
the plugins itself is not the issue, the callback function for onChange event is defined like so:

```
function showPreview(coords)
{
    var rx = 100 / coords.w;
    var ry = 100 / coords.h;

    $('#preview').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * 500) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * 370) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
    });
};
```

so the real question is how to enable a preview using the css styles used here, but with the image supplied as a background attribute. see the [demo](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples-callback.html) of the plugin.

Comment: have you tried jcrop plugin for jquery a different jquery crop ?

Comment: both plugins have similar callback function. see my update above for clarification of the question

Comment: If i understand correctly this is what is happening: the droppable plugin is setting the background image of the `div`(?) and the cropping plugin is getting the `img` element that has a transparent image in it?

Comment: ok this is what happens when you drag and drop over the image, some divs are created which have position absolute which go over your original image so it can calculate the cordinates of the new image, in the mean time it also uses the preview box, where it copies the image, then shows only a portion of the image using css margins and width. The questions is why do you need to use the background attribute and not leave it as it is? also check my answer, not sure if it will deff work but could set you on right tracks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function preview(img, selection) {
    var scaleX = 100 / (selection.width || 1);
    var scaleY = 100 / (selection.height || 1);
    // console.log($(img).attr('src'));
    $('#preview + div').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * 400) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * 300) + 'px',
        "background-image": 'img_src',
        "background-position": '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px '+ '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px',
    });
}
```

`$('#preview');` should be a div,

`var img`, should hold the link to src which you might have to capture it from it. use the `console.log` commentted above to see if it would give you the src of image, then use it at the `img_src` to provide the image

Answer (score 0):

you are correct James.
I did need to add another line though:

```
"background-size": Math.round(scaleX * 400) + 'px ' + Math.round(scaleY * 300) + 'px'
```

the background-position and background-size did the trick.

btw, the img variable does hold the source, but that was not the issue has i save different versions of the image (different sizes) with the data() method.

thanks!